# MouseDown Wrong Event Target

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

My goal is get `mousedown` event from `id="node-2"` element. But when I do mousedown event target not coming from `id="node-2"`. coming from child elements.

My vue codes is below.

```html
<div @mousedown.left="mouseDown" id="node-2" class="absolute w-[200px] h-auto border border-black rounded select-none z-[1000]">
   <div class="w-full bg-yellow-500">header</div>
   <div class="bg-white">content</div>
</div>
```

```js
mouseDown(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log(event)
}
```

This is apperiance.

[image: node]

This is `console` data when I do `mousedown` to header or content.

[image: consolelog]

I want to see this in console. it does not matter, what I do `mousedown` to header or content.

[image: goal console]

Comment: This is not a Vue specific problem but is standard HTML behavior.  To get the element with the actual event listener on it from the event, use `event.currentTarget` rather than `event.target`

Comment: @yoduh thanks for comment. your are right. I get it now. :)

Comment: use `event.currentTarget`

Answer (score 0):

try this in console.log  to access parent div I hope to  be useful

```
   mouseDown( event) {
         console.log(event.target.parentElement);
    }
```

Comment: your right for this situation. but this is not dynamic using. for example, if there are many two children, like child-> child-> child `div`, this is not works correctly. but if you use `event.currentTarget`, it works correct all time.